# how to return same alert dialog when user entered invalid values then click ok?

Tags: android, alert

I am working with `AlertDialog` for user login to an application.I have displayed two edit views for enter user name and password and also I have used positive button and negative button on alert dialog.When the user entered invalid user name or password then click on ok i am displaying a text on same alert dialog with TexView but the alert dialog is closing.How can i stay with alert dialog till user enter valid details on edit text feilds?

i have implemented code for get the alert as follows:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Login here");
    alert.setView(table);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        objLogin.setLoginUsrName(userNameText.getText().toString());
        objLogin.setLoginPassword(passwordText.getText().toString());

        if(objLogin.userValid())
        {

          //getting next screen


        }
        else{
            invalid.setText("Invalid user name or password");
            invalid.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            //diaplay same alert here with invalid text

        }

      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                 //get register screen code here
      }
    });

    alert.show();
```

How can i show the alert till user entered valid details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the positiveButton and negativeButton from the AlertDialog class.  AlertDialog closes after pressing these.  You might have better luck with a Dialog Builder instead of an AlertDialog, but I haven't tested that.

Another fix:

Try adding two Android  widgets to your 'table' layout, and setting an onclicklistener on them.  Do this instead of the two default positive/negative buttons from the AlertDialog. This approach will also allow you to modify the placement and style of the buttons.

Comment: But how can i close alert dialog when user is valid?

Comment: call `alert.dismiss();`  inside the onClick() method.  You will have to make `alert` a `final` variable, but that should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom view for the `AlertDialog` that contains two buttons and use those buttons for the positive and negative.

But it would be MUCH better to call `startActivityForResult` to a login activity if user is not logged in. Then in the `onActivityResult`, if user didn't put anything in (chose to cancel, or press back key), then just finish the first activity that launched. And on the login activity that you make, button presses would be the same, and if the login info is correct, then you'd call `finish`.

I used to use an `AlertDialog` in my app for login. I now use the method I stated above, and I like it mjuch better.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom dialog using the following layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="150dip" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" >  

        <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/edusername"
            android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:inputType="textPassword"
             android:singleLine="true" ></EditText>
    </TableRow>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" >  

        <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/edconfirmpwd"
            android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="50dip" android:inputType="textPassword"
             android:singleLine="true" ></EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:text="@string/BtnOk" >
</Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:text="@string/cancelBtn" >
</Button>

    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

in the activity use

```
    final Dialog password = new Dialog(activity.this);
        password.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        password.setTitle("Enter your login ids");
                final EditText getUsername = (EditText)password.findViewById(R.id.edUsername);
        final EditText getPassword = (EditText) password
                .findViewById(R.id.edconfirmpwd);
        Button okButton = (Button) password.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String password= getPassword.getText().toString();
String username = getUsername.getText().toString();

                if (password.equals("yourText")&& username.equals("yourtext")) {
password.dismiss();

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "InvalidPassword",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
password.show();

                }





            }
        });
        Button cancelButton = (Button) password.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Entered on cancel button clicked");

                password.dismiss();

            }
        });
        password.show();

    }
```